# Cost effectiveness of replacing brass door knobs and hinges

Tags: doors

We have a home built in the 70's with antique brass hinges and door knobs.  We are thinking of possibly downsizing in the next few years and I'm wondering if it would be beneficial not only for aesthetics but resale to replace all the hinges and knobs.  We have already replaced the cream electrical outlets and covers to white for a more updated look.

Comment: If they are actually brass, just clean them. I would never replace actual brass hardware with anything unless it is broken.

Comment: Do you mean the hardware is actual brass or just has a fake brass plating on it? If it's actual brass then by all means keep it. It's valuable and expensive. If it's just fake brass plating then yeah, replacing it with something more modern looking might be worth it.

Comment: Use a magnet to check if it is brass or not.